# Java String.format args indexing inconsistency

Tags: java, string, indexing, string-formatting

In Java you can use the String.Format function to make formatted strings. You also have the possibility to reference the args of the function in the order you wish, by using the `i$` in the format string, where `i` is the index of the parameter you are referencing. Unfortunately, it doesn't entirely seems to be consistent, because the following two lines of code yield the same exact result:

```
String.format("My name is %0$s and I am %2$d years old", "Joe", 20);
String.format("My name is %1$s and I am %2$d years old", "Joe", 20);
```

Why does 0 and 1 both refer to the same element? Isn't it supposed to be a strictly 1-based indexing instead of zero-based?

Comment: JVM might be smarter than you are.  It may recognize that only one argument fits the %d format and matches accordingly.

Comment: @duffymo Not exactly the case. Here it is `Joe` that is being matched with both index `0` and `1`, not the integer argument

Comment: Yes only the 20 matches for decimal formatter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it does not recognize `0$`, because the index starts from 1. Hence, it fetches the argument based on the position of that `%s`. Over here your `%0$s` is the first reference for an argument and hence it takes the first argument `Joe`.

You can run and see the difference between:

```
 String.format("%s %1$s %2$d", 1, 20, 13);
 Output: 1, 1, 20
 String.format("%s %0$s %2$d", 1, 20, 13);
 Output: 1, 20, 20
```

Comment: I still find it very puzzling why it's implemented this way, because things like this can have inconsistent output: `String.format("%s, %0$s, %1$s, %2$s, %3$s, %4$s", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);` But I accept your answer as the answer.